# PHP grabbing Year and Month

Tags: php, date

```
   $str = $in_Date;
   echo " " . $str;
while(! feof($str)){
   $letter = parse_str($str);
   echo " " . $letter;
}
    $date = array("$letter");
    echo " " . $date[0];
    echo " " . $date[1];
```

So for example $in_Date=20131016 so YYYYMMDD

What I want to do is but each character in an array so then I can grab 0-3 which would be the year then grab the month 3-4..

it works all the way to the line before the while statement... So i think my while statement is wrong

Comment: You might want to look at using `str_split` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php

Comment: Since you know the position of each element, try `substr` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use [**`DateTime::createFromFormat()`**](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php). It makes parsing your date trivial and lets you use all of the formatting options available with dates.

```
$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('Ymd', $in_Date);
echo $dt->format("Y"); // prints out the year
echo $dt->format("m"); // prints out the month
```

Comment: Got it and thank you.. I like trying the hard way lol that is weird out of like 100+lines of code I never heard about createFromFormat or ran accross it

Comment: This is how many of us find stuff out. We take the scenic route and than someone shows us a better way. :)